# How do I write an array to a text file without overwriting it

Tags: c#

This is the code i use to create the text file.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\****\Desktop\File.txt", array);
```

How do I append text to an existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Appends lines to a file, and then closes the file. If the specified
>   file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified
>   lines to the file, and then closes the file.

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\****\Desktop\Passwords.txt", array);
```

Comment: I get an error "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string' " this is more of my code "List<string> UsernamesAndPass = new List<string>();
            UsernamesAndPass.Add(Title);
            UsernamesAndPass.Add(Username);
            UsernamesAndPass.Add(Password);
            UsernamesAndPass.Add(Spacer);
            UsernamesAndPass.ToArray();

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\ivar\Desktop\Passwords.txt", UsernamesAndPass);"

Comment: @IvarDulphinHansgaard Didn't see the text you were appending was an array, thought it `UserAndPassword` was a `string`. Use `File.AppendAllLines` instead.

Comment: @IvarDulphinHansgaard Welcome.

Comment: @IvarDulphinHansgaard You forgot to star out your name in the paths you u posted in the comments... lol.

Comment: @IvarDulphinHansgaard I also advise you not to store plain usernames and passwords in a text file, or in plain memory like that.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have shown you how to append a single string to a text file. If you naturally have a collection of *lines*, however, you probably want [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\****\Desktop\File.txt", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\****\Desktop\Passwords.txt")) 
{
    sw.WriteLine(UsernamesAndPass);
}
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx